# Finding the range of values on a HTML form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, alert

I am new to using JavaScript and I am currently trying to find the range between values submitted in an HTML form. Five values are submitted, named E1 - E5, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" size="2" name="E1" pattern="[0-9mM]{2}" 
onKeyup="autotab(this, document.tri_1.E2)" maxlength=2 autofocus 
autocomplete="off"/>
```

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkScores(){
        var eOne = document.getElementById("E1").value;
        var eTwo = document.getElementById("E2").value;
        var eTheee = document.getElementById("E3").value;
        var eFour = document.getElementById("E4").value;
        var eFive = document.getElementById("E5").value;

        var scoresArray = [eOne, eTwo, eThree, eFour, eFive] ;
        var scoresMax = Math.max(scoresArray) ;
        var scoresMin = Math.min(scoresArray) ;

        var scoresDifference = scoresMax - scoresMin ;

        if (scoresDifference > 10)
        window.alert("The inputted scores have a range of more than 1 whole mark. 
        Do you want to accept these scores?") ;
    }
</script>
```

The form has a submit button which I would like the script to be carried out before saving the scores to a MySQL database:

```
<input type="submit" name="saveNext" 
value="Save and load next competitor" onSubmit="checkScores()" />
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Adswayne...tell us what is wrong with the above code.  Are you receiving an error, are you receiving a bad result, etc?  We need more info

Comment: @MikeTWebb I'm not receiving any error, but the alert is not appearing and so I'm not sure if there is an issue with one of the variables or something. It seems as if the whole script isn't running at all!

Comment: @Adswayne...try putting an alert at the very beginning of your function().  It's possible the alert isn;t firing because scoresDifference <= 10

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Math.max` and `Math.min` with an array.

You have two solutions:

```
var scoresMax = Math.max(eOne, eTwo, eThree, eFour, eFive);
// ...
```

OR

```
var scoresMax = Math.max.apply(null, scoresArray);
// ...
```

(See [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))

Comment: Thank you - I have just tried both solutions but unfortunately neither have caused the function to run. The form runs correctly and the values are stored in the database, but it appears as if the script is being ignored completely.

Comment: Note also that you can't put newlines in alerts (use `\n` instead), and that you should either return `false` or use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) (better) to actually cancel the sumission.